# Not being able to add column(Python)

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

So I've run a certain calculation in a loop, and obtained the results which are stored in a list-store1:

```
for st in store1[:10]:
    print (st)
0
4
1
0
0
1
2
3
1
1
```

I have a dataframe **dd**, and I would like to add the values of store1 to it as a separate column. I've run the following code:

```
for st in store1[:40000]:
    dd['Parts_needed']=st
```

But instead of the actual values, what I get is:

```
dd.Parts_needed.head(10)
Out[40]: 
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
```

Can somebody help me out here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need `dd['Parts_needed'] = store1[:40000]` ? What is `print (dd.head())` ?

Comment: oh lol, it is actually this simple ;p got it..thanks. What is wrong with the one that I did though?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, `dd.Parts_needed` is Series, so you get expected output.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code:

```
dd['Parts_needed'] = store1[:40000]
```

But is necessary same length of `DataFrame` and `list`.

---

Also each column of `DataFrame` is `Series`, so you get expected output.

For check need first 5 rows of all column use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
 print (dd.head())
```